# the command to delete a slice of a line plot

Tags: dm-script

search it in the help document, could not find it.

is something like: LinePlotImageDisplayDeleteSlices(LinePlotImageDisplay lpid)

Delete.LinePlotImageDisplayGetSlice ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you are seeking
>
> `Boolean ImageDisplayDeleteSliceWithId( ImageDisplay id, ScriptObject slice_id )`
>
> used in combination with
>
> `ScriptObject ImageDisplayGetSliceIdByIndex( ImageDisplay id, Number slice_index )`

Example copied from the F1 help documentation of GMS 3.3:

```
image CreateRandomSpectrum( number sx )
{
 image img := RealImage( "Spectrum", 4, sx )
 number fac =  Random() * 3
 number off =  Random() * 10
 number mag =  Random() * 3
 img = mag * sin( ( off + fac * icol / iwidth ) * Pi() )
 return img
}   

imageDisplay CreateAndShowMultiSlice( number nSlice, number sx )
{
 image firstImg := CreateRandomSpectrum(100)
 firstImg.ShowImage()
 imageDisplay disp = firstImg.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
 for( number i = 1; i<nSlice; i++ )
         disp.ImageDisplayAddImage( CreateRandomSpectrum(100), "" )

 disp.LinePlotImageDisplaySetLegendShown( 1 )
 return disp
}

void DemoRemoveSlice()
{
 imageDisplay disp = CreateAndShowMultiSlice(5,100)
 OKDialog( "Now remove 2nd slice" )
 object id = disp.ImageDisplayGetSliceIDByIndex( 2 )
 disp.ImageDisplayDeleteSliceWithId( id )
}

DemoRemoveSlice()
```

Comment: image img=getfrontimage()

Rotateleft (img)

showimage(img) 

imageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplayChangeDisplayType(3)

disp.lineplotimagedisplaysetlegendshown(1)

Number slicecount= disp.LinePlotImageDisplayCountSlices ()

disp.ImageDisplaySetSliceLabelByID(1,N )

disp.ImageDisplayDeleteSliceWithId( 13)
disp.ImageDisplayDeleteSliceWithId( 12 ),  tried both delete and set labels, they are not working, what is the reason?

Comment: @together All the 'byID' commands require an 'ID' *object* not a value. See the example above where you first get the object from the index and then use this object as parameter.

Comment: thanks, actually not fully understand. I will try to practice and to see how to let the code works in my case

Comment: @together Do you have time at the moment to join me in a chat here:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199439/chat-with-together

Comment: sorry, I missed the chat with you. one more question, in your example, you create a display with CreateAndShowMultiSlice(5,100),  but for an exist image, how could we know the object id of the slices?  For example, I have a line plot image, it includes 13 slices, in the legend their labels are Slice0, Slice1, Slice2, ... I would like to delete the slice7,   and change the label of slice9, do I need to set ID for them, or the ID of them already exist, I just need to know what they are?

Comment: You get the Id object from the index just like in the example above. That is what the command GetSliceIdByIndex is for. So the first slice is getsliceidbyindex(0) the index May change by resorting of slices, but the I’d stays the same.

Comment: @together and instead of CreateAndShowMuktislice you just use getfrontimage().imagegetimagedisplay(0) to get the lineplot’s display

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199446/discussion-between-together-and-bmyguest).